# DRF login generate token and session at the same time

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My site uses Django Rest Framework with an angular frontend and knox tokens for login. I want to add django-wiki to my site and right now it works, except users that login to my site who want to visit the wiki have to login again because django-wiki uses session authentication and my site uses tokens.

Is there a way for a DRF login action to return both a token and a session?